# Receive interface as parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm learning Typescript and I'm creating a custom React hook to fetch data from the api:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import api from '../services/api';

interface RequestProps {
    url: string;
    initialLoading: boolean;
}

interface ResponseProps<T> {
    data: T,
    error: boolean,
    loading: boolean
}

export const useApiRequest = <T>({ url, initialLoading }: RequestProps): ResponseProps<T> => {
  // Response state
  const [data, setData] = useState<T>();
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(initialLoading);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchApi = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);

        // Fetch data from REST API
        const response = await api.get<T>(url);
        setLoading(false);
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(true);
      }
    };

    // Call async function
    fetchApi();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [url]);

  return {
    data,
    loading,
    error,
  };
};
```

What I'm trying to do is to receive the `T` interface as a parameter and assign it to `data`, since the `data` will be different, according to the API response from different `url`. So whenever I call this hook, I want to pass a custom interface for `data`, like:

```
const {data, loading, error} = useApiRequest<MyCustomInterfaceForData>({url: 'https://apiurl', initialLoading: true})
```

The problem is that Typescript is giving me an error in the `data` from the return statement:

> TS2322: Type 'T | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.   'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T | undefined'.     Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T'.       'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'undefined'.  useApiRequest.ts(10, 5): The expected type comes from property 'data' which is declared here on type 'ResponseProps'

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all, `data` can be undefined until `response.data` is used for updating the state(`data`).

So, try changing the type of response like this:

```
interface ResponseProps<T> {
    data: T | undefined,
    error: boolean,
    loading: boolean
}
```

Comment: Wow how stupid I was! Thank you for troubleshooting this